# How to i search for more hits then one dropdown list at the same time on a sharepoint list

Tags: powerapps, sharepoint-list

If I have a sharepointlist

- Color, Kategory
- Green, Chair
- Blue, Table
- Blue, Chair

On the gallery, I can use

```
Filter(Möbler;Color = DropdownColor.Selected.Value)
```

or I can use

```
Filter(Möbler;Kategory = DropdownKategory.Selected.Value)
```

But I don't understand how I can make a double filter where I want to choose
them at the same time.
With a **AND** or a **OR** or maybe 3 filter.

Answer (score 0):

You would just add them together like:

```
// AND
Filter(
  Möbler;
  Color = DropdownColor.Selected.Value &&
  Kategory = DropdownKategory.Selected.Value
)

// OR
Filter(
  Möbler;
  Color = DropdownColor.Selected.Value ||
  Kategory = DropdownKategory.Selected.Value
)
```